# How to write a program called biggest that takes any number of arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So i am trying to write a program called biggest that takes any number of arguments. For all the 
arguments that are files, it finds the file with the most words in it, and prints a line 
such as:

**File whatever has largest number of words (37)**

assuming the file called "whatever" has 37 words, which is more (or the same) as 
any other files in the current directory. If no arguments were valid files, then the 
following line should be printed to stderr: **biggest: no valid filenames were specified**

The `wc` command seems like it would be useful, especially `wc –w`

please guide me with more help!!

Thanks

Comment: Can you post any code that you have already written?

Comment: This seems like homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in a script and enjoy :

```
for i; do  wc -w $i; done | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

**PS: No one wants to help when you don't help yourself. For me it was timepass ;-)**